# String termination or dangling pointer?

Tags: c, shell, pointers, posix, clion

From the output `foo �` do you agree thats it looks like I have an issue with string termination? I have written a custom shell but when I run the command `echo foo` then I get some junk `char` that looks like a dangling pointer or a string that wasn't terminated:

```
/home/dac/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/openshell-69ebaaf9/69ebaaf9/Debug/openshell
'PATH' is set to /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin.
dac:/home/dac/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/openshell-69ebaaf9/69ebaaf9/Debug $ ls
 {ls}
19660: executing ls
CMakeCache.txt  cmake_install.cmake  openshell
CMakeFiles  Makefile         openshell.cbp
dac:/home/dac/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/openshell-69ebaaf9/69ebaaf9/Debug $ echo foo
 {echo} {foo}
19669: executing echo
foo �
dac:/home/dac/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/openshell-69ebaaf9/69ebaaf9/Debug $
```

It doesn't say anything in the debugger or in the Clion analysis, but from the output it looks clear that I didn't terminate the string. Do you agree? How can I debug it in Clion? If I run it in `gdb` then nothing interesting appears. I'd like to learn to use the debugger so that I can actually inspect values at run-time.

### Update

It did say something in the debugger when I was careful. It turns out that a hadn't terminated an argument: `{"echo", "foo", 0x....}` should have been `{"echo", "foo", 0}` and when I fixed it the program runs fine without the junk `char` (that was `0x2525252525...`).

[image]

So I changed the code a little:

```
static int runCmd(const char *cmd) {
    const char *cp;
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    struct command shellcommand[4];
    char **argv;
    int argc = 1;
    bool pipe = false;
    char *command[40];
    char *cmd2[20] = {"cmd2", 0};
    int numberofpipelines = 0;
    unsigned long i3 = 0;
    unsigned long i2 = 0;
    unsigned long i1 = 0;
    unsigned long n = 0;
    char *string;
    char *string1;
    int maxgrep = 1;
    cmd2[0] = NULL;
    cmd2[1] = NULL;
    cmd2[2] = NULL;
    command[0] = NULL;
    command[1] = NULL;
    command[3] = NULL;
    char *string2 = NULL;
    for (cp = cmd; *cp; cp++) {
        if ((*cp >= 'a') && (*cp <= 'z')) {
            continue;
        }
        if ((*cp >= 'A') && (*cp <= 'Z')) {
            continue;
        }
        if (isDecimal(*cp)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (isBlank(*cp)){
            continue;
        }
        if ((*cp == '.') || (*cp == '/') || (*cp == '-') ||
            (*cp == '+') || (*cp == '=') || (*cp == '_') ||
            (*cp == ':') || (*cp == ',') || (*cp == '\'') ||
            (*cp == '"')) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    makeArgs(cmd, &argc, (const char ***) &argv, pipe);
    char a[20] = {0};
    if (sscanf(cmd, "%*[^']'%[^']'", a) == 1) {
        printf("<undefined>");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        if (argv[i] != NULL && strstr(argv[i], "|")) {
            numberofpipelines++;
            char subbuff[40];
            i1 = 0;
            i2 = 0;
            i3 = 0;
            subbuff[0]='\0';
            string = strstr(argv[i], "|");
            if (string != NULL) {
                i3 = string - argv[i];
            }
            string1 = strstr(&argv[i][i3 + 2], "|");
            if (string1 != NULL) {
                i2 = string1 - argv[i3 + 1];
                printf("i2: %lu", i2);
            } else {
                char *found3 = strstr(&argv[i][i3 + 1], " ");
                if (found3 != NULL) {}
                string2 = strstr(argv[1], "|");
                if (string2 != NULL) {
                    i1 = string2 - argv[1];
                }
                n = strlen(argv[1]) - i1;
                if (argc > 2) {
                    memcpy(subbuff, &argv[i][i3 + 1], n - 1);
                    subbuff[n - 1] = '\0';
                    cmd2[0] = subbuff;
                    cmd2[1] = argv[argc - 1];
                } else {
                    memcpy(subbuff, &argv[i][i3 + 1], n);
                    subbuff[n] = '\0';
                    cmd2[0] = subbuff;
                    cmd2[1] = argv[argc - 1];
                }
                argc++;
                argv[i + 1] = subbuff;
                command[i] = "<undefined>";
                argv[i + 2] = NULL;
                maxgrep = i;
            }
        }
        if (argv[i] != NULL) {
            if (i < maxgrep) {
                command[i] =  argv[i];
                command[i+1] =  0;
                maxgrep++;
            } else {
                command[maxgrep] =  argv[maxgrep];
            }
        }
        if (argv[i] != NULL) {
            char *p = strchr(argv[i], '|');
            if (!p) {
                /* deal with error: / not present" */;
            } else {
                *p = 0;
            }
        }

    }
    dump_argv((const char *) "d", argc, argv);
/*  makeArgs(cmd, &argc, &argv, pipe);*/
 /*   command[2]= 0;*/
    shellcommand[0].argv = command;
    shellcommand[1].argv = cmd2;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork failed");
        return -1;
    }
    /* If we are the child process, then go execute the program.*/
    if (pid == 0) {
        /* spawn(cmd);*/
        fork_pipes(numberofpipelines, shellcommand);
    }
    /*
     * We are the parent process.
     * Wait for the child to complete.
     */
    status = 0;
    while (((pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) < 0) && (errno == EINTR));
    if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error from waitpid: %s", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pid %ld: killed by signal %d\n",
                (long) pid, WTERMSIG(status));

        return -1;
    }
    return WEXITSTATUS(status);
}
```

And now the output looks better.

```
/home/dac/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/openshell-69ebaaf9/69ebaaf9/Debug/openshell
'PATH' is set to /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin.
dac:/home/dac/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/openshell-69ebaaf9/69ebaaf9/Debug $ echo foo
i rcommand {echo} {foo}
926: executing echo
foo
dac:/home/dac/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/openshell-69ebaaf9/69ebaaf9/Debug $
```

Comment: Not necessarily. You could be printing some sort of "un-pritable" character(s)

Comment: Could be missing termination, dangling pointer, undefined behavior, correct code behavior, mis-transcription, ...  Many possibilities.

Comment: I found it when debugging. I was calling `exec` and those parameters need to end with a `0` for example `{"echo", "foo", 0}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect the string value just before the output. If you use printf and just a POD char array, make sure the final character is '\0', and it is where it should be (the string is terminated correctly and no garbage at the end). If you are in C++ using std::string, make sure it is constructed with the correct value (same rules as before) and let C++ stdlib handle output and formatting. It seems you have some unprintable data at the end.